# How to overwrite protected afterSave method in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to overwrite \Magento\Widget\Model\ResourceModel\Widget\Instance _afterSave method to save another page_group field in the database.

```
/**
 * Perform actions after object save
 *
 * @param \Magento\Widget\Model\Widget\Instance $object
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _afterSave(AbstractModel $object)
{
    $pageTable = $this->getTable('widget_instance_page');
    $pageLayoutTable = $this->getTable('widget_instance_page_layout');
    $connection = $this->getConnection();

    $select = $connection->select()->from($pageTable, 'page_id')->where('instance_id = ?', (int)$object->getId());
    $pageIds = $connection->fetchCol($select);

    $removePageIds = array_diff($pageIds, $object->getData('page_group_ids'));

    if (is_array($pageIds) && count($pageIds) > 0) {
        $inCond = $connection->prepareSqlCondition('page_id', ['in' => $pageIds]);

        $select = $connection->select()->from($pageLayoutTable, 'layout_update_id')->where($inCond);
        $removeLayoutUpdateIds = $connection->fetchCol($select);

        $connection->delete($pageLayoutTable, $inCond);
        $this->_deleteLayoutUpdates($removeLayoutUpdateIds);
    }

    $this->_deleteWidgetInstancePages($removePageIds);

    foreach ($object->getData('page_groups') as $pageGroup) {
        $pageLayoutUpdateIds = $this->_saveLayoutUpdates($object, $pageGroup);
        $data = [
            'page_group' => $pageGroup['group'],
            'layout_handle' => $pageGroup['layout_handle'],
            'block_reference' => $pageGroup['block_reference'],
            'page_for' => $pageGroup['for'],
            'entities' => $pageGroup['entities'],
            'page_template' => $pageGroup['template'],
            'action_buttons' => $pageGroup['action_buttons'],
        ];
        $pageId = $pageGroup['page_id'];
        if (in_array($pageGroup['page_id'], $pageIds)) {
            $connection->update($pageTable, $data, ['page_id = ?' => (int)$pageId]);
        } else {
            $connection->insert($pageTable, array_merge(['instance_id' => $object->getId()], $data));
            $pageId = $connection->lastInsertId($pageTable);
        }
        foreach ($pageLayoutUpdateIds as $layoutUpdateId) {
            $connection->insert(
                $pageLayoutTable,
                ['page_id' => $pageId, 'layout_update_id' => $layoutUpdateId]
            );
        }
    }

    return parent::_afterSave($object);
}
```

Is there any way that i am missing to overwrite this method without using a preference and copy the whole class content in my module? (the whole class because there is the call to parent::_afterSave() so i have to extend from parent - \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb to avoid hard-coding of parent class)

Thanks